# Usuário editando todas suas respostas

Tags: debate, contas-usuário

O [usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/53431) pelo visto decidiu excluir a sua conta, e decidiu excluir o conteúdo de todas suas respostas da rede também, exemplos: ([1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/181899/revisions)), ([2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/184154/revisions)), ([3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182382/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-cont%C3%ADnua-e-entrega-cont%C3%ADnua/182396#182396))

Me ponho no lugar do usuário, afinal tudo que ele postou, aparentemente é de autoria dele, mas tem respostas muito bem feitas e com gratificação inclusive, perderiam todo o contexto se realmente forem apagadas.

É o caso de reverter tudo?

Comment: Eu acredito que deve reverter o conteúdo, mas como não sou mod, não tenho muita opinião a dar!

Comment: Particularmente eu acho que o correto era banir o usuário e reverter as respostas para não perder conteúdo potencialmente relevante. Quando você pede demissão de uma empresa não tem o direito de deletar seus códigos desenvolvidos enquanto esteve lá. Pode não ser o mesmo caso mas é um pouco similar

Comment: Aproveitei e fiz rollback nas edições que faltavam.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Foram tomadas providências para estancar o problema. Vamos ver se ele percebe que não há vantagem em fazer isto.

De fato pelos termos de uso e licença ao que o usuário está sujeito ao publicar aqui na rede o conteúdo não é de propriedade de ninguém, nem dele, nem da rede. Ele pode conservar a autoria sempre tanto quanto ele quiser, inclusive a autoria deve ser preservada mesmo se copiado para outro lugar fazendo referência ao original.

Ele tem o direito de dissociar sua conta das perguntas se achar que não quer mais que o conteúdo tenha qualquer vínculo com ele. Ele tem que pedir isso. Ele não deve saber que isto é possível.

Estamos aguardando para ver qual é a melhor solução definitiva.

Se realmente ele não quer que o conteúdo de qualidade dele (ou pelo menos o bem classificado) não continue sequer aparecendo anonimamente pode ser considerado vandalismo. Entendemos a primeira ocorrência dele e óbvio que vamos presumir boa fé, mas não pode continuar acontecendo.

Se tiver alguma informação que tenha um claro motivo que não possa ser publicado, até pode ser removido, mas pelo que vi não é o caso.

Obrigado pelo aviso, ambos foram importantes, ainda que o sistema também tenha avisado.